# Preventing Brute Force Attack on MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, asp.net-mvc-5, brute-force

I am trying to figure out how to fight a brute force attack on my website.  Based on all the research I have done the top answers were Account Lockout & Captcha.

If I lock out a user then I am denying them service for x amount of time.  This means that if an attacker were to attack 10 different accounts he will lock them all.  Then when time is up he will lock them again.  Basically he can keep at it and keep the users locked out indefinitely.  The users can contact me but that is now 10 tickets I would have to deal with and I'd rather avoid that work if its possible.  So what I am failing to understand exactly is how is this then useful?  The attacker might not get into account but they will cause me and users a lot of grief.

How do I combat this?  Ip banning seems pointless as it can be changed fairly easy.

Comment: Offtopic. Not a programming questions (yet). Try the webmaster site instead.

Comment: This link has a great write up on different methods, I have used the password delay one myself before.  https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Blocking_Brute_Force_Attacks

Answer (score 9):

You can add an incremental delay that doubles after each failed login attempt, after a handful of login attempts the delay gets too long for brute force to work (e.g. after 20 attempts the delay is 6 days).

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel viewModel, string returnUrl)
{
    // incremental delay to prevent brute force attacks
    int incrementalDelay;
    if (HttpContext.Application[Request.UserHostAddress] != null)
    {
        // wait for delay if there is one
        incrementalDelay = (int)HttpContext.Application[Request.UserHostAddress];
        await Task.Delay(incrementalDelay * 1000);
    }

    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return View();

    // authenticate user
    var user = _userService.Authenticate(viewModel.Username, viewModel.Password);

    if (user == null)
    {
        // login failed

        // increment the delay on failed login attempts
        if (HttpContext.Application[Request.UserHostAddress] == null)
        {
            incrementalDelay = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            incrementalDelay = (int)HttpContext.Application[Request.UserHostAddress] * 2;
        }
        HttpContext.Application[Request.UserHostAddress] = incrementalDelay;

        // return view with error
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
        return View();
    }

    // login success

    // reset incremental delay on successful login
    if (HttpContext.Application[Request.UserHostAddress] != null)
    {
        HttpContext.Application.Remove(Request.UserHostAddress);
    }

    // set authentication cookie
    _formsAuthenticationService.SetAuthCookie(
        user.Username,
        viewModel.KeepMeLoggedIn,
        null);

    // redirect to returnUrl
    return Redirect(returnUrl);
}
```

There's more details at [this post](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2015/06/03/csharp-incremental-delay-to-prevent-brute-force-or-dictionary-attack)

Comment: Nice, thanks! I guess some small print : a) the benefits will be diluted slightly if there's a large (non-sticky routed) server farm managing logins; b) users NATted to the same IP will be subject to the same penalty as any miscreant user, and vice versa, miscreant will benefit from a successful login by a user on the same IP, and c) because the next doubling is only applied AFTER the delay, it means a heavily parallelized attack would also dilute the effectiveness.

Answer (score 2):

Don't display the user id used to log in publicly. Have a separate display id. For example, they might log in with their email address and choose a different name to display. If an attacker doesn't have the user id then he can't make repeated login attempts and lock another user out.

Comment: I do have this implemented already.  But even then he can get mass emails from another site and just start going at it.  My error messages are also in such a way not to give away if account is locked out or anything so they wouldn't know if they got it right but I'm wondering if there is anything I can do to actually stop them?

Comment: Some CDN services like Incapsula or Akamai help. Their primary purpose is as a CDN so all requests to your domain go through their servers. That allows other features like blocking requests from certain domains. They might even be able to proactively block domains if they detect suspicious activity.

Comment: how much overhead would this add to the page loads?  Would the load time be affected by much?

Comment: The primary purpose of the CDN is to reduce time on page loads, because static content is served to clients from the CDN's servers which are spread out geographically and can add other optimizations. It should improve load time.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [PoliteCaptcha](https://github.com/NuGet/PoliteCaptcha), which only displays the captcha if JavaScript is disabled (as in most automated scripts) or when the first submit attempt fails. This makes the captcha invisible to most of your normal users, but a PITA for spammers.